# Any implementations of C++0x out there?

Tags: c++, c++11

Other than Microsoft's upcoming VC10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[here](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) is a good breakdown of c++0x support in several major compilers

Answer (score 7):

You can run `g++ -std=c++0x` for mostly-compatible C++0x implementation.

From the manual:

```
 c++0x
   The working draft of the upcoming ISO C++0x standard. This option enables experimental features that are
   likely to be included in C++0x. The working draft is constantly changing, and any feature that is enabled
   by this flag may be removed from future versions of GCC if it is not part of the C++0x standard.
```

As a stupid little example of it in action:

```
$ cat a.cpp    
const int FOO_VERSION = 2;

int main() {
    static_assert(FOO_VERSION >= 3, "Your version of Foo doesn't contain the necessary bugfixes to run this program correctly.");
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -std=c++0x a.cpp
a.cpp:1:17: error: stdio: No such file or directory
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:6: error: static assertion failed: "Your version of Foo doesn\'t contain the necessary bugfixes to run this program correctly."
```

Also, as @GMan mentioned in a comment, [GCC's list of C++0x compatibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) can be found online.

Comment: AFAIK all the thread and lock related stuff is missing yet, right?

Comment: List of supported features and their corresponding g++ version: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: The thread and lock stuff aren't listed on the features page, but the headers files are included with gcc 4.4 and the contents look like the new standard.

Comment: @Caspin: The library status is tracked [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x).

Answer (score 1):

Comeau -- try it out [here](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/). And no, I don't work for/affiliated with them ;) But they do a good job of compliance.

Intel also supports [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler#Versions) C++0x starting with 11.0. (The current version is 11.1)